# Examples of cases where it is easier to define the negation of a property than the property itself

Tags: definition, big-list

Are there cases in mathematics where it is easier to define the negation of a property $P$ than property $P$ itself? I would like several answers giving examples of such cases. Basically, I am looking for examples in math texts and papers where the author first defines the negation of a property, then negates the definition to get the property itself.

Comment: I've always found "disconnected" easier to define than "connected" for topological spaces.

Comment: I think it's a little easier to define linear dependence than linear independence in linear algebra. I've no idea what texts do.

Comment: @Ethan: you can say that vectors $v_i$ are linearly independent if $\sum c_i v_i = 0$ implies each $c_i = 0$.